# Giving output of CNN to LSTM

Tags: python, keras, deep-learning, conv-neural-network, lstm

I have an input of shape (64,500,10) where 64 is the batch size, 500 is the length of my input and 10 are the total features I have. I create a CNN followed by a Fully connected neural network using keras:

```
inputt=Input(shape=(x_train.shape[1],x_train.shape[2]))
output=Conv1D(filters=64, kernel_size=4, activation='relu')(inputt)
output=MaxPooling1D(pool_size=4)(output)
output=Dropout(0.2)(output)
output=Conv1D(filters=64, kernel_size=4, activation='relu')(output)
output=MaxPooling1D(pool_size=4)(output)
output=Dropout(0.2)(output)
output=Flatten()(output)
output = Dense(32,activation='relu')(output)
output=Dropout(0.5)(output)
output=Dense(32,activation='softmax')(output)
output=Dropout(0.5)(output)
output=Dense(2,activation='softmax')(output)
model = Model(inputs=inputt, outputs=output)
model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy', optimizer='adam', metrics=['accuracy'])
```

What I want to do is pass the output of CNN to LSTM instead of fully connected neural network and then pass the output of LSTM to dense layer. How can I achieve this? How can I use the output of CNN to give it to LSTM.

Comment: Instead of `Dense` layer you can add `LSTM` after the `Flatten`

Comment: That I do understand. I am more confused about the input shape to LSTM?